# How does .exist work in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find 4 of my posts that has an image. I am using this code:

```
  Post.find({}, function (err, posts) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', 'An unknown error has occurred.');
      res.redirect('back');
    } else {
        res.render("home", {posts});
      });
    }
  }).exists(image, true).limit(4).sort( { date: -1 } );
```

one post looks :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("586e15b21f647007ec22a171"),
    "title" : "Some title is here",
    "category" : "node",
    "body" : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "image" : "1486300310990-14775211410_42b8d244da_o.jpg",
}
```

So a post which doesn't have any image should be skipped.
like this:

```
  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("586e15b21f647007ec22a171"),
        "title" : "Some title is here",
        "category" : "node",
        "body" : "some txt"
    }
```

But it doesn't work fun, would you please help me?

Comment: Have you defined the image as part of the model? Can you show the model?

Comment: Yes I have. It is better to find 4 posts where image length is greater that 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post.find({'image' : {$exists : true}}, function (err, posts) {
 if (err) {
      req.flash('error', 'An unknown error has occurred.');
      res.redirect('back');
    } else {
        res.render("home", {posts});
      });
    }
});
```

try the above code.

updated code...

```
  Post.find({$or : [{image: {$exists : true}},{image: ''}]}, function (err, posts) {
         if (err) {
              req.flash('error', 'An unknown error has occurred.');
              res.redirect('back');
            } else {
                res.render("home", {posts});
              });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks but what should I do to check the length? a user may delete its image later on and image will be ''.  I want it ti skip empty string as well. Do you know how to do that?